# Unable to integrate ng2-material and angular2-material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have been using [angular2-material](https://www.npmjs.com/~angular2-material) for material design components in angular2. It solved most of my use-cases but some components that I needed are missing in the library (modals, submenus, etc).
I found [ng2-material](https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material]) and have been trying to use both.

With importing ng2-material, I ran into npm issues and haven't been able to figure them out.

Here's the relevant part of my package.json

```
...
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular2-material/button": "^2.0.0-alpha.5-2",
"@angular2-material/core": "2.0.0-alpha.5-2",
"@angular2-material/input": "^2.0.0-alpha.5-2",
"@angular2-material/list": "^2.0.0-alpha.5-2",
"@angular2-material/sidenav": "^2.0.0-alpha.5-2",
"@angular2-material/toolbar": "^2.0.0-alpha.5-2",
"@angular2-material/icon": "^2.0.0-alpha.5-2",
"@angular2-material/slide-toggle": "^2.0.0-alpha.5-2",
"ng2-material":"0.4.1"
...
```

And this is the dependency error that I ran into

```
app@0.0.0 /path/to/my/project/ui-angular
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/router@2.0.0-rc.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular2-material/checkbox@^2.0.0-alpha.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular2-material/progress-bar@^2.0.0-alpha.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular2-material/progress-circle@^2.0.0-alpha.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular2-material/radio@^2.0.0-alpha.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY es6-promise@>=3.0.2
`-- ng2-material@0.4.1 


npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/path/to/my/project/ui-angular/node_modules/material-design-icons/package.json'
npm WARN ng2-material@0.4.1 requires a peer of @angular/router@2.0.0-rc.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-material@0.4.1 requires a peer of @angular2-material/checkbox@^2.0.0-alpha.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-material@0.4.1 requires a peer of @angular2-material/progress-bar@^2.0.0-alpha.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-material@0.4.1 requires a peer of @angular2-material/progress-circle@^2.0.0-alpha.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-material@0.4.1 requires a peer of @angular2-material/radio@^2.0.0-alpha.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-material@0.4.1 requires a peer of es6-promise@>=3.0.2 but none was installed.
```

Is it even possible to use the 2 libraries in conjuntion?